# Ragel and NSMutableString

Tags: objective-c, regex, unicode, ragel

Is it possible to make Ragel work over NSMutableString?

I would like to use Ragel to generate DFA to tokenize an NSMutableString. That "mutable" part means that I cannot use `cStringUsingEncoding:` whenever single one character changes. As far as I can see, there are two problems:

1. The examples included with Ragel seem to use `char *` to get a character even in Objective C. But I don't know how to get a pointer to the ever changing NSMutableString. Is it perhaps possible to force Ragel to use `characterAtIndex:` instead? Wouldn't that be slow?
2. If I understand correctly, NSString might change its internal representation at runtime, i.e. it is not always UTF-16. For example, when it contains ASCII only, it uses single-byte encoding. But as soon as there appears a character outside the valid range, it switches to multi-byte encoding. Is it somehow possible to account for that in Ragel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I'd use `CFStringRef` directly, since it has [CFStringCreateMutableWithExternalCharactersNoCopy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringCreateMutableWithExternalCharactersNoCopy), which allows you to declare your own buffer and explicitly disables the optimisations you're talking about.

Also, if you setup your `externalCharactersAllocator` correctly, you might even benefit from toll-free bridging (though that *might* not work) so it doesn't get too messy for whatever mutates the string.